# Dúvida com PostgreSQL (Sum & Count)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Pessoal beleza? estou estudando SQL com Postgres e venho me dando bem porém tenho um exercicio para fazer o qual embolou minha cabeça e não consigo resolver, e queria que vocês me ajudassem não somente me mostrando como faz mas também me explicando um pouco sobre o problema para eu conseguir entender o porque de cada coisa!

Eu tenho o seguinte problema que nao consigo somar o numero de vendas e nem o valor total das vendas do mês :(

**Listar o Ticket Médio do mês de janeiro para cada loja ativa, retornando:

- Código unidade de negócio
- Valor do Ticket Médio da Loja

Dicas:

- O "ticket médio" é calculado em função do valor das vendas totais não canceladas/estornadas de

  uma empresa divididas pelo número de vendas.
- Utilizar as seguintes tabelas: unidadenegocio, venda**

Até agora o que eu consegui fazer foi isso...

```
    select
    unidadenegocio.id,
    venda.id,
    venda.valortotal,
    venda.datahorafechamento

    from
    unidadenegocio
    left join venda on venda.unidadenegocioid = unidadenegocio.id

    where datahorafechamento >= '2020-10-01'
    and datahorafechamento <= '2020-10-31 23:59:59';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar a cláusula GROUP BY e a função de agregação AVG.

```
SELECT
    unidadenegocio.id,
    AVG(venda.valortotal)
FROM unidadenegocio left join venda on venda.unidadenegocioid = unidadenegocio.id
WHERE datahorafechamento >= '2020-10-01 00:00:00'
  AND datahorafechamento <= '2020-10-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY unidadenegocio.id;
```

Para o PostgreSQL você pode simplificar sua cláusula WHERE com:

```
WHERE date_trunc('month', datahorafechamento) = '2020-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp;
```

No lugar de AVG poderia utilizar SUM / COUNT.

Comment: Entendi, porém como ficaria para eu somar o total das vendas do mês e os valores totais das vendas e exibir em uma coluna ?
Eu queria pegar todos dados listados da coluna venda.id e contar quantas vendas foram no mes, juntar tudo isso. Depois pegar todos valores das vendas e somar tudo e exibir o total e então a partir disso eu divido as vendas pelo valor total

Comment: Pesquise sobre WINDOW Functios https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html